# Javascript setInterval on multiple lines successively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, setinterval

I need to scroll multiple lines of text within a table, one-by-one. When the last line is reached, the first line is supposed to scroll again, and so on and so on (See Fiddle for better understading)

[image]

I already implemented the table so far (see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaq9bbwy/2/)) but i'm having a rather strange problem: In the first 'round' averything works fine, but when i reach the last line, then set the first line scrolling, this one scrolls twice as fast.

I can see this is because i never call `clearInterval` on the initial movement, but when i do, every other movement also stops (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uaq9bbwy/4/)).

How do i get the first line to scroll at normal speed?

Edit: As Requested, the relevant code:

```js
var arrScrollTexts = Array({
  'text': $('#text1'),
  'marquee': $('#marq1')
}, {
  'text': $('#text2'),
  'marquee': $('#marq2')
}, {
  'text': $('#text3'),
  'marquee': $('#marq3')
});


var speed = 50;
var cntTexts = 0;
var indent = 0;
var movingText;

var marquee = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].marquee;
var text = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].text;

setMovement(marquee);

function setMovement(mar) {
  var movement = setInterval(function() {
    mar.scroll()
  }, speed);
  return movement;
}

function unsetMovement(mov) {
  clearInterval(mov);
}

marquee.scroll = function() {
  indent--;

  marquee.css('text-indent', indent);
  // If the end of the Text is showing, set line to normal
  if (indent < -1 * (text.width() - marquee.width())) {
    indent = 0;
    marquee.css('text-indent', indent);
    cntTexts++;

    // If last line is scrolling: Set first line as next line
    if (cntTexts == arrScrollTexts.length) {
      cntTexts = 0;
    }

    // Select next line
    text = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].text;
    marquee = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].marquee;

    // unset current movement of line, set next line moving
    unsetMovement(movingText);
    movingText = setMovement(marquee);

  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="marq1">
      <span id="text1">
            The Second round this line goes twice as fast. Trollolo...
          </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="marq2">
      <span id="text2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="marq3">
      <span id="text3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Relevant code is quite a lot, so i created a fiddle for a better overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Don't need to stop & start the interval again & again.`marquee.scroll()` is already resetting the indent to 0 once scroll completes for each row. You just need to remove the `unsetMovement()` & `setMovement()` from the `marquee.scroll()`

```js
var arrScrollTexts = Array({
  'text': $('#text1'),
  'marquee': $('#marq1')
}, {
  'text': $('#text2'),
  'marquee': $('#marq2')
}, {
  'text': $('#text3'),
  'marquee': $('#marq3')
});


var speed = 50;
var cntTexts = 0;
var indent = 0;
var movingText;
var marquee = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].marquee;
var text = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].text;

setMovement(marquee);

function setMovement(mar) {
  var movement = setInterval(function() {
    mar.scroll()
  }, speed);
  return movement;
}
marquee.scroll = function() {
  indent--;
  marquee.css('text-indent', indent);
  // If the end of the Text is showing, set line to normal
  if (indent < -1 * (text.width() - marquee.width())) {
    indent = 0;
    marquee.css('text-indent', indent);
    cntTexts++;

    // If last line is scrolling: Set first line as next line
    if (cntTexts == arrScrollTexts.length) {
      cntTexts = 0;
    }
  // Select next line
    text = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].text;
    marquee = arrScrollTexts[cntTexts].marquee;
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="marq1">
      <span id="text1">
            The Second round this line goes twice as fast. Trollolo...
          </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="marq2">
      <span id="text2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="marq3">
      <span id="text3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```